# Weird noise waveform on signal line

Tags: power, noise, interference, waveform

I'm doing some electrode recordings and a large noise waveform keeps appearing on the oscilloscope (see pic attached). Interestingly the recording set-up functions just fine with a clearly distinguishable signal for about 3.5 minutes after powering on before a large amount of high frequency and high amplitude noise kicks in which quickly giving way to the waveform in question that persists until the power is cut off. If the system is powered back on less than 3.5 minutes after the waveform occurred, it comes back in less than 3.5 minutes; if the system is off for longer than 3.5 minutes it takes about 3.5 minutes to show up again. The power supply rails are +-15V and I'm in the US so wall power is 120V 60Hz. There is an amplification stage and a multiplexer before the oscilloscope input. The electrodes have an on board pre-amp stage and there is 10 feet of unshielded power (5V) and data cables bundled together going to the electrodes.

Has anyone ever seen something like this? The frequency of the waveform makes me think it has something to do with the wall power or that it could be a ground loop but the large time constant is a bit confusing.

[image: oscilloscope waveform]

Comment: What is an "electrode recording"? Some kind of physiological measurement, e.g. probing the action potential of a cell? What is the waveform supposed to look like, can you post a screenshot of the "good" signal for comparison? What circuitry are you using for amplifying the signal?

Comment: A 3.5 minute time constant strongly suggests a thermal issue. Have you monitored your +/- 15 volt supplies? I suspect a power supply problem.

Comment: Are you using a differential probe?  You might be causing some grounding issue, but that usually shows up much more quickly than 3.5min... unless you are dumping current through an inductor that is heating up until it no longer responds properly.

Comment: Are there any big machines operating periodically nearby? Like an air compressor or HVAC system?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast -- do you think the power supply itself is overheating, or one of the circuits being powered by it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond -- no, just a few computers

Comment: @hw22s - I'd suspect the power supply first, but either is possible. The reason I say that is because I suspect that the circuitry is exposed to the air, while the power supply comes in a nice closed box, and heat always builds up better in enclosed spaces. But get some idea of the current draw of your circuitry (that is, ALL of the loads on the power supply), then get a resistor with about the same current draw and power. If the circuit starts oscillating, check the power supply. If it is bonkers, remove all circuitry and replace with the resistor. If the problem persists, it's the supply.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption it is a thermal problem in combination with an oscillation of your set up.
Use a hair dryer to heat up and look if the time will be shorter until the oscillation appears.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! A thermal problem with the power supply itself or with the connecting circuitry?

Comment: Could you provide a circuit diagram? I don't know exactly how you circuit looks like and for further hints I need more to know.